# What's the recommended way of running Java from PHP 5.2?

Tags: java, php, php-5.2

I want to call Java from PHP 5.2, running either on a webserver or from a command line script.

From PHP 4, this seems to be simple, and just involves installing the [PECL Java extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.java.php).

Example code from the PHP 4 extension:

```
<?php
  // get instance of Java class java.lang.System in PHP
  $system = new Java('java.lang.System');

  // demonstrate property access
  echo 'Java version=' . $system->getProperty('java.version') . '<br />';
?>
```

However, this extension doesn't exist on PHP 5.

What is the closest alternative for PHP 5?

**edit:**

Really I'm looking for an interface similar to *either* a C PHP extension or to that provided by the PHP 4 Java extension.  The Java program is fairly small and only needs to retain a small amount of state between calls and doesn't need to run asynchronously.  The PHP script would only be running a small number of instances simultaneously.

This would also need to be deployed to multiple machines (running Ubuntu 9.x and Debian Lenny), so it should be simple to install.

Comment: How to do this depends a lot on your use case. Can you elaborate a bit on the thing you are actually trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This project seems to be a good bet: http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/

Comment: +1 for this; I've used it before and for me it was a pig to set up but eventually seemed to work OK.  Didn't make for extremely readable code though...

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to keep state at the java site I'd either use a java process that listens on a plain socket or use a simple embedded webserver ([winstone](http://winstone.sourceforge.net/) or [jetty](http://www.mortbay.org/jetty/)) if you are more fluent writing servlets. Some other possibilities are listed at this related question: [What is the best approach for IPC between Java and C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165945/what-is-the-best-approach-for-ipc-between-java-and-c)

Answer (score 0):

Now quite what you asked for, but you could have a look at Caucho's [Resin](http://caucho.com/resin/doc/), and in particular their [Quercus](http://quercus.caucho.com/) which is a 100% Java implementation of PHP, it [allows integration of Java and PHP](http://quercus.caucho.com/quercus-3.1/examples/quercus-module/index.xtp).

Comment: Thanks, but yeah I don't want to change my PHP environment that radically to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I have a project that uses a Java program to fetch some data. It's quite simple, but I found that

```
 $java_command="cd /var/java_dir && java my_java_program $myparam1 $myparam2";
 $result=exec($java_command,$output,$return_code);
```

works just fine.

Comment: It's a possibility, but it's a little bit crude, and I'd like to be able to store some state between calls.

Comment: Sure, for that I write to a database or a file. I'm sure there are more sophisticated solutions out there.

Answer (score 0):

[Zend Server](http://www.zend.com/en/products/server/) also has a built-in daemon allowing you to access Java functionality from within PHP.  It works right out of the box.